# Export Package [Eclipse]

Tags: application-development, python, eclipse, packaging, development

I am just wondering how do I export a .deb package for Ubuntu Software Centre in Eclipse? I have created an application that runs Python and Webkit now I wish to submit to the Software centre. How do I export a .deb file?

Comment: Is it open source?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Debian package integration for Eclipse.

I suggest you read the [packaging guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/).

If you have a working `setup.py` then packaging Python is fairly simple.